# How to add multiple items to a flatlist using textinput?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-native-flatlist

i'm trying to add items to a flatlist via textinput. at the moment i can only add one item and when i try to add a second it just updates the first item, although the data from the textinput should appear below the previous textinput. i have found a few instances of a similar kind of problem and i know that i probably need to add something to my code but i just can't figure out what. below is my code. i would be grateful for any kind of help :)

```
function FlatlistComponent({ }) {

    const listItems = [];
    const [arrayHolder, setArrayHolder] = React.useState([]);
    const [textInputHolder, setTextInputHolder] = React.useState('');

    useEffect(() => {
        setArrayHolder(listItems)
      }, [])

    const joinData = () => {
        listItems.push({ name : textInputHolder });
        setArrayHolder(listItems);
    }

    const FlatListItemSeparator = () => {
        return (
            <View
                style={{
                height: 1,
                width: "95%",
                backgroundColor: '#00678A',
                alignSelf: 'center'
                }} />
        );
    }

    // Delete note
    deleteNote = id => () => {
      const filteredData = arrayHolder.filter(item => item.id !== id);
      setArrayHolder({ data: filteredData });
    }

    return (
        <View style={styles.MainContainer}>

          <FlatList
            data={arrayHolder}
            width='100%'
            extraData={arrayHolder}
            keyExtractor={(item) => item.id}
            ItemSeparatorComponent={FlatListItemSeparator}
            renderItem={({ item }) => <Text style={styles.item} onPress={deleteNote(item.id)}> {item.name} </Text>}
          />

          <TextInput
            placeholder='Kirjoita uusi'
            onChangeText={data => setTextInputHolder(data)}
            style={styles.textInputStyle}
            underlineColorAndroid='transparent'
            clearTextOnFocus={true}
            value={listItems}
          />

          <TouchableOpacity onPress={joinData} style={styles.button} >
            <Text style={styles.buttonText}> + </Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>

        </View>
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`listItems` is always an empty array after component re-rendered, you should concat previous arrayHolder with new item:

```
const joinData = () => {
  setArrayHolder([... arrayHolder, {name: textInputHolder }]);
  // or use update function
  // setArrayHolder(prev => [...prev, {name: textInputHolder }]);
}
```

Comment: thank you! i encountered another problem after solving the previous one. my deleteNote function seems to delete all list items at once and not just one. do you have any advice on that?

Comment: I think it's caused by incorrect data format. change this `setArrayHolder({ data: filteredData });` to `setArrayHolder(filteredData);`

Comment: looks like you forgot to declare `deleteNode`? try `const deleteNode`

Comment: that's not the problem, `deleteNote` doesn't need `const`

Comment: what is the format of your `listItems`, can you print their data structure?

Comment: oh, i see, there is no `id` prop for every single item in your listItems, 
you must give the item `id` when you adding them

Comment: by the way, you should learn how to debug code, you can use console.log or developer tools provided by browser

Comment: thank you for your help! and yeah i definitely should learn to debug code. is there any easy way to add id?

Comment: you can use a ref or declare a variable outside component to save current id, while your are adding an item, assign the newest id into object, like this `{ id: ++id, name: textInputHolder }`

Comment: i added these `let i = 1;` `{name: textInputHolder, id: i++}` and it's still not working, the added items are deleted all at once

Comment: do you have any more advice?